# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 92

Tags: java, excepciones

estoy haciendo un explorador de archivos TXT con netbeans, una de las cosas que debe hacer mi explorador es contar el numero de vocales que se encuentran escritas dentro del TXT. Para poder contar el numero de vocales estoy utilizando el siguiente código

```
 private void btnNumVocalesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        //String resp = "";
        
        int NoVocales = 0;
        char vocal;
        texto = txtarea.getText();
        for (int i = 0; 1<texto.length(); i++)
        {
            vocal = texto.charAt(i);
            if (vocal =='a'||vocal=='e'||vocal=='i'||vocal=='o'||vocal=='u'||vocal =='A'||vocal=='E'||vocal=='I'||vocal=='O'||vocal=='U')
            {
                NoVocales++;
                //System.out.println(NoVocales);
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Nº de vocales: "+NoVocales);
        
    }
```

Cuando mando a correr el programa este sí cuenta el número de vocales del TXT pero no imprime ningún resultado con el JOptionPane e imprime el error (la línea 285 es en la que escribo vocal = texto.charAt(i);)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 92
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at interfazproyecto.Grafica.btnNumVocalesActionPerformed(Grafica.java:285)
    at interfazproyecto.Grafica.access$500(Grafica.java:17)
    at interfazproyecto.Grafica$6.actionPerformed(Grafica.java:131)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; 1<texto.length(); i++)` has puesto `**1** < texto.length()`, es `**i** < texto.length()`. Te sales del índice porque nunca estás comprobando que la variable `i` siga dentro del rango permitido.

Comment: Tienes muchas razón, gracias por la correción.

Answer (score -1):

Veo que se solucionó a partir de un comentario pero como leí aprovecho para darte algunas sugerencias que noté para las buenas practicas:

- Los nombres de variables deberían comenzar en minúscula y debe usarse camel-case, los nombres de clase son los que empiezan con mayúscula. Es decir `noVocales` en lugar de `NoVocales`.
- Podrías extraer tu validación de si es vocal (`vocal =='a'||vocal=='e'||vocal=='i'||vocal=='o'||vocal=='u'||vocal =='A'||vocal=='E'||vocal=='I'||vocal=='O'||vocal=='U'`) a un método para darle mas legibilidad al código. De la mano de esto, no estas contemplando vocales con acentos, guarda con ese escenario.
- Podrías reducir tus comparaciones utilizando `indexOf` que ofrece String de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
if("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(vocal) != -1)
```

Por si queres leer mas de [String.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-), basicamente al String al que le haces el *indexOf* (en este caso *"aeiouAEIOU"*) tratas de buscar en que posición del String se encuentra el *char* que le pasamos como parámetro y de no encontrar el char devuelve **-1**, por lo que siempre que encuentre el char en la cadena va a retornar un valor entre *0* y el largo de la *cadena - 1*. Por eso si no encuentra el valor es **-1**.

- Como último, la variable `vocal` no es requerida, y que hagas esto `vocal = texto.charAt(i);` tampoco es necesario, puedes comparar directamente desde `texto.charAt(i)` de esta forma te evitas una asignación de variable por cada iteracion del for.

Comment: Otra cosa, renombraría la variable `noVocales` si bien se puede entender que hace referencia a **numero de vocales**, otra persona podría interpretarla como **no vocales** (literal, los char que no son vocales) y pensar que ahí almacenas la cantidad de no vocales siendo que la variable almacena lo contrario. Le pondría `numeroVocales`, `numVocales`, `cantVocales`. `totalVocales` .... etc. En fin, resumir el nombre siempre y cuando sea claro y no haga doble sentido. Saludos!